# Two different FCM notifications received depending if app is opened or closed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having this bizarre behavior in FCM (Firestore cloud messaging).

The bizarre behavior I'm talking about is this, when I send a notification to my phone and the app is currently open I get the good message with the correct style (it has a cover image)

When I send this same notification and my app is in the background, I don't get the correct styling (there is no cover image)

What could be wrong here? (Android development is really giving me a hard time)

Here's my code to handle upcoming notifications in FCM

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    private void showNotification(String title, String body, Map<String, String> data) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.my.app.alarm";

        // Build cover url
        String coverURL = "";
        if (data.containsKey("cover")) {
            coverURL = "https://localhost" + data.get("cover") + ".jpg";
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Reminder Channel");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }


        // TO open New added Games fragment
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("FragmentFromNotification", "NewAddedReleases");
        PendingIntent notificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentIntent(notificationIntent)
                .setContentInfo("Info");

        // Load new game cover here
        if (!coverURL.isEmpty()) {
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            try {
                bmp = Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(coverURL).get();
                NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bps = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bmp);
                notificationBuilder.setStyle(bps);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(), notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onMessageReceived` is provided for most message types, with the following exceptions:

- Notification messages delivered when your app is in the `background`. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
- Messages with both notification and data payload, when received in the `background`. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

In short when your app is in background notification is handled by `system tray`.

Add these lines inside the `application` tag to set the custom default icon and custom color:

> Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming
>   notification messages.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
```

> Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when
>   no color is set for the incoming notification message.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

[REFERENCE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple?authuser=0)

Comment: So there is no way to set the cover image for a notification? Do I change the type of message I send from my back end to something else than notification?

Comment: You can set image for the notification

Comment: The problem is my app will like always be in the background when my users receive the notification, does this mean they will never have the complete notification with the image and the intent that opens the correct fragment I added in my showNotification method ?

Comment: No not at all!!